# In Android what does the dimension %p mean?

Tags: android, android-layout

I've been looking through some of the Android examples on the [developer website](https://web.archive.org/web/20120430122646/http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SoftKeyboard/res/xml/qwerty.html), and I've seen `%p` being used as a dimension.

I've done a Google search, but can't find any information about what it means. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Check out the [keyWidth](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/Keyboard.html#attr_android:keyWidth) documentation for an explanation.

> the optional %p suffix provides a size
>   relative to some parent container

Comment: Think of it like: "percent (%) of (P)arent" width, although the relative size isn't necessarily out of 100.

Answer (score 8):

1. 50%   is the centre of the animated view (relative to view).
2. 50%p  is the centre of the view’s parent (relative to parent).
3. 50    is 50 pixels from the top/left of the animated view (absolute).

Answer (score 4):

Answer of @Cheryl Simon and @zero_cool is correct.
And I add the demo for easy to understand

(The below gray view height is `200dp`, not `400dp`)

[image]

Layout code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_animate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Animate"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="// A gray view with 200dp height"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:background="#aaa"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="#f00"
            android:text="50dp height View"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/image_1"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:background="#f00"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:text="animate with %"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/image_2"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:background="#f00"
            android:text="animate with %p"
            />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Animation file**
`slide_in.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:duration="5000"
        android:fromYDelta="25%"
        android:toYDelta="0"/>
</set>
```

`slide_in_with_p.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:duration="5000"
        android:fromYDelta="25%p"
        android:toYDelta="0"/>
</set>
```

**Activity code**

```
button_animate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Animation slide = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.anim.slide_in);
        Animation slideWithP = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.anim.slide_in_with_p);

        viewAnimateWithPercent.startAnimation(slide);
        viewAnimateWithPercentP.startAnimation(slideWithP);
    }
});
```

[DEMO](https://github.com/PhanVanLinh/AndroidAnimationWithPercentP)