# %p in android animation

Tags: android, animation, translate-animation

I'm confused about %p unit in  animation.
Here is my anim file test.xml

```
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
    android:duration="1000"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:fromXDelta="0"
    android:toXDelta="0"
    android:fromYDelta="50%p"
    android:toYDelta="50%p" />
```

And I use this animation for my view

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="#ff2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:id="@+id/view" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And after animated, the view is nearly center the screen, as I expected.
[image]

But, if I change the position of the view to center it's parent, and the position of the view after animation is not correct

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="#ff2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:id="@+id/view" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the result:
[image]

I think for the same parent, 50%p is alway the same, but the result is not. Why?

Comment: see this post : http://stackoverflow.com/a/4412183/5519005

Comment: is the 50%p mean: currentY + 50% * parentHeight?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try

```
android:fromYDelta="0%p"
android:toYDelta="50%p"
```

then you will see your  animated in 1000ms

so

- the `android:fromYDelta=` means the start position based on viewself
- the `android:toYDelta=` means the end position based on viewself

when you set the View `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"`
,the View animated from top to center.

when you set the View `android:layout_alignParentCenter="true"`
,the View animated from center to bottom.